# C# String manupulation

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to substring following  message into an Array.

```
"message": "patient.FirstName : First Name is required\r\npatient.LastName : Last Name is required\r\n"
```

Expected output:

[0] -> `First Name is required`

[1] -> `Last Name is required`

What is the easiest and efficient way to parse this?
Can I use regex?

Note: I'ts ok to use following delimiters: :, `\r\n`

Can anyone post an example?

Comment: [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to be an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with regex:

```
var s = "patient.FirstName : First Name is required\r\npatient.LastName : Last Name is required\r\n";
var m = Regex.Match(s, ".*?: (?<fn>.*?)\\r\\n.*: (?<ln>.*?)\\r\\n", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var a = new string[] { m.Groups["fn"].ToString(), m.Groups["ln"].ToString() };
```

Output:

```
[0] "First Name is required"    string  
[1] "Last Name is required" string
```

Comment: Mixing lazy and greedy quantifiers will work in C# correctly, but it is definitely not good practice. Why not use negated character classes, BTW?

Comment: @stribizhev, I am just started learning regexes. Do you mean something like this: `[^:]: (?<fn>([^\\]+))[^:]+: (?<ln>([^\\]+))`? This end up with 51 step instead of 152 above. You can add your solution and we all can learn something from it :)

Comment: I do not answer questions without efforts shown. They are often deleted with all the rep points you might get. Not worth effort. And I would use `String.Split`.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgi I'ts works as expected.